# Start reading txt after match with line.startswith and until next line.startswith

Tags: python

I have a very large txt file, containing events (integer numbers, always incrementing) and some information for each of them. An example:

```
=== 0 ===
Start: 4.8
End:   4.8
=== 1 ===
Start: 4.8
End:   4.8
=== 2 ===
Start: 4.8
End:   4.8
--- device1 ---
15, 309, 1, 1, 4.8
15, 310, 1, 1, 4.8
16, 309, 1, 1, 4.8
756, 93, 1, 1, 4.8
756, 94, 1, 1, 4.8
--- device2 ---
15, 329, 1, 1, 4.8
=== 3 ===
Start: 4.8
End:   4.8
=== and so on ===
```

I am interested in fiddling with the information from one such specific event.

If I want event 1, it skips everything before `=== 1 ===` and until (but excluding) `=== 2 ===`

If I chose event 2, it will contain more lines (always fluctuating based on the event).

Some simple code I tried:

```
def get_event_no(line):
    return re.search(r'\d+', line).group()

if line.startswith("==="):
    if event_number == get_event_no(line): # compare with a user-given integer
        # here I would read all lines (and do something with them), but I don't know how to read starting from here onward and until next line.startswith("===").
```

Any hints on how to proceed? Can also be just indications and no code :). If you are thinking of a flag, how to set this up for this particular situation?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two solutions to this. First: read each line as you go and stop when you get to the `=== 2 ===`. Instead: you can search the whole file for `=== a ===` and `=== b ==` and then use the data collected between those two lines.

Here's the first solution outlined:

```
contents = file.read().split('\n')
reading = False
for line in contents:
  if line == "=== " + str(a) + " ===":
    reading = True
  elif line == "=== " + str(a+1) + " ===":
    break
  elif reading:
    # do your data processing here.
```

Here's the second solution outlined (and what I would use):

```
line_start = [i for i in range(len(contents)) if contents[i] == "=== " + str(a) + " ==="][0]
line_end = [i for i in range(len(contents)) if contents[i] == "=== " + str(a + 1) + " ==="][0]
readable_data = contents[line_start:line_end]
# now you can process your data here.
```